# How to populate a HTML table by querying existing SQLite table based on search using Flask?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I have a SQLite table where I store multiple columns, 3 of them are `Product Name`, `Description` and `Like`. I want a user to be able to search for Product Names, add the product data as rows in a HTML table and press if the user likes the Product or not. This should then update the SQLite `Like` column for the selected products.

As you can see in the code below, I am trying to fetch the "name" which is entered by the user, and filter the SQLite table for the data and print it in a table. But I do not know how to write the line where I filter the SQLite table, as marked below.

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template, redirect
import os
from models import db, Products

app = Flask(__name__)

# Create dummy secrey key so we can use sessions
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
# Create in-memory database
app.config['DATABASE_FILE'] = 'mna.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + app.config['DATABASE_FILE']
db.init_app(app)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
   products = []
   name = request.args.get('search')
   products.append(Products.productname == name)  ##<-- I don't know how to write this line correctly
   return render_template('index.html', products=products)

# run Flask app
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug = True)
```

`models.py`

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Products(db.Model):

   productid= db.Column(db.String(), primary_key=True)
   productname= db.Column(db.String(), primary_key=False)
   description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
   like = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False)

def __str__(self):
    return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

def __unicode__(self):
    return "Name: {productname}; Description : {description}".format(productname=self.productname, description=self.description)
```

And my `index.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="GET">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search for Product.." name="search">
        <button type="submit"><i class="search-container"></i></button>
    </form>
    <div class="product-container" style="overflow: auto; max-height: 80vh">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table" id="products">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Description</th>
                        <th scope="col">Like</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for product in products %}
                    <tr ={{ product .productid}}>
                        <th scope="row">{{ product .productname}}</th>
                        <td> {{ product.description }} </td>
                        <td> {{ product.like }} </td>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use query interface from SQLAlchemy,

Use either,

1. [filter](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) or
2. [filter_by](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by)

Try,

```
db.session.query(Product).filter(Product.productname == name)
or
db.session.query(Product).filter_by(productname = name)
```